# Codeigniter correct JOIN request

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I have 2 tables with next construction & data:

Table 1 - events:

```
id  name    about          owner_id
1   Event1  <description>  2
2   Event2  <description>  1
3   Event3  <description>  2
4   Event4  <description>  2
```

And table 2 - event_follows

```
id   event_id   user_id
1    1          2
2    4          2
```

I need to get all events for current user (i.e. user with id 2) and join count of followers for this event. Now I'm using this code:

```
    $this->db->select('events.*, COUNT(event_follows.id) as followers')
            ->from('events')
            ->where('events.owner_id', $id); // $id - equals 2

    $this->db->join('event_follows', 'event_follows.event_id = events.id', 'left')
            ->group_by('event_follows.event_id');
```

All seems to be ok, but there is a problem. This code returns only 2 events of 3 - events with id 1 & 4. As I understand, this happens because there is no followers for event 3.

So how to correctly fetch all events and get count of it's followers, including those that have 0 followers?

Comment: Are you getting valid results for events 1 and 2 even when you have multiple event_follows entries for those event_ids? I'd expect the group_by to always return a value of 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get all rows from the `events` table you need to group by `events.id` as opposed to `event_follows.event_id`

```
$this->db->select('events.*, COUNT(event_follows.id) as followers')
        ->from('events')
        ->where('events.user_id', $id); // $id - equals 2

$this->db->join('event_follows', 'event_follows.event_id = events.id', 'left')
        ->group_by('events.id'); //change to events.id
```